# WIF - optional authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, wif

I'm working on a proof of concept app. The basic functionality works, where I can log into one website, link to another site that shares the same STS, and the partner site picks up the credentials properly.
However, the partner site only requests the token if the page that we link to requires authentication (which kind of makes sense I guess).

Ideally, I'd like to link to a partner page that does not require you to be authenticated, BUT if the user IS already authenticated, I'd like to at least be able to recognize them on the partner site.
Currently, if my partner landing page does not require authentication, it doesn't appear that the user is logged in when they arrive. As soon as the user requests a page on the partner site that does require authentication, it then grabs the token without requiring the user to log in.

I've tried playing around with the SecurityTokenReceived and RedirectingToIdentityProvider events, but so far I'm stumped.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem you are running up against is in dealing with the [SessionAuthenticationModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.sessionauthenticationmodule.aspx) hijacking the request.  This module is responsible for detecting if the user has a valid session (based on a cookie that is written upon a successful redirect from the STS) and if not, to redirect the user to the STS to fetch a valid token.  The [WSFederationAuthenticationModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.aspx) supplies the eventing necessary to hook into various stages of the redirection/authentication process.

Based on your description, it sounds like you want the following to happen:

1. User clicks on a link that redirects to the partner site
2. At the partner site, the request is intercepted and the system determines if the user is signed-in to the STS or anonymous
3. If the user has a valid session with the STS, then pull the claims for that user

The problem is, your RP cannot know that the user has a valid session without sending the user to the STS first (the RP's do not talk to each other or the STS.  The user's brower is used as the means of communication between the RP's and the STS in the form of WS-Fed directives and SAML tokens passed in the url during redirects).  If the user is sent to the STS, then they must authenticate, which could be a problem for anonymous users.

So, I do not think there is a "trick" that you can pull via configuration or interception of the request to determine if the user has a valid session with the STS.  You *might* be able to pass a hint, however, from the referrer that is intercepted by the partner site.  This hint could take the form of a parameter on the url that indicates to the partner site that the current user has a valid session and to go ahead and redirect to the STS (absence of this hint would indicate an anonymous user).  You could also build a system to "hand-off" knowledge of the signed-in user using a resource that both sites have access to (i.e. database).

As you are sure to learn soon, more often than not, WIF offers pieces to the puzzle, but every situation is different and you have to supply the other pieces on your own.

Hope this helps!